# "Делай, словно знаешь как это делается" - пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите корректно написать предложение:

*Делай, словно знаешь как это делается*.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: *Делай, словно знаешь, как это делается*.

Answer (score 1):

Делай, **словно** знаешь,  **как** это делается.

Постановка запятых соответствует **интонации** (здесь явная трехчастная конструкция), но вот интересно **определить грамматику.**

Можно сравнить: Делай **как знаешь**. Этот оборот с  союзом КАК не обособляется, так как входит в основное сообщение (является обстоятельством в простом предложении). Но: Делай так, **как знаешь** (неполное придаточное образа действия при наличии указательного слова в главном предложении).

**В нашем случае:** Делай (так), словно (ты) знаешь, как это делается. Это неполное сравнительное придаточное (союз СЛОВНО) и придаточное изъяснительное предложение (союз КАК), последовательное подчинение.

Answer (score 0):

Ну две же основы:

ты знаешь, это делается, -

разделять их будем, м?

Главное (делай, словно знаешь) и придаточное изъяснительное (как это делается). Сложноподчиненное то есть предложение.

> Запятой отделяются также неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные
>   предложения, например: *Он не понял, в чём дело; Рад помочь, чем
>   смогу; Запомнил, чему учили; Люди знают, что делают; Сделайте, что
>   нужно; Могу представить всё, что угодно; Он понимает, что к чему;
>   Садитесь, где свободно; Ругали все, кому не лень; Встретимся, знаете
>   где; Болтал, не знаю что.*
>
> Но: *Делай что хочешь* и т. п., см. § 114, п. 1.

([§ 114. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxix.html#sect114.1))