«Знаешь, как лучше?» Нужна запятая?
Нужна ли запятая во фразе?
Знаешь, как лучше?

Смотрите здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426495/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%88%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/426517#426517

● Знаешь, как лучше?
Я считаю, что запятая нужна. Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором и главное, и придаточное являются неполными:
[Ты] Знаешь, как лучше [сделать, сказать, написать, оформить...]?
• Сравните (без запятой): Знаешь как?

4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится: <...>
3) если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия...

• Цельным по смыслу выражением не является.
• Примеры
— Не знаю, — прошептала она. — Не знаю, как лучше... (В. Ф. Панова. Времена года. Из летописей города Энска).
— Не знаю, сможем ли мы договорится о правилах игры, но надеемся, что федеральные власти осознают, что мы профессионалы и знаем, как лучше (Наталия Осипова... «Коммерсантъ-Daily»).
— Это ни о чем не говорит!
— Потому, что я твой отец, и я знаю, как для тебя лучше!
— Знаешь, как лучше? Ты в этом так уверен?
Ольга Дашкова. Грешница
Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения

 Нужна ли запятая во фразе? Знаешь, как лучше?


Правильно: ЗнАешь, как лУчше? Или: Ты всегда знАешь, как лУчше.

А откуда сомнения? Это же придаточное предложение. — Похоже на устойчивое сочетание по Розенталю.

Это контаминация двух других вариантов: (1) Делай как знаешь (по-своему). (2) Хотеть как лучше (желать добра).

Эти устойчивые сочетания используются в значении одного слова.

А почему заданное предложение не является устойчивым?  А  у него нет значения одного слова, Кроме того, там произношение с двумя ударениями.

Сравним два варианта:


Ты всегда знАешь, как лУчше. Ты всегда хочешь как лУчше, // да не получАется.
Но возможно и так: Ты всЕгда хочешь, // как лУчше.

ВЫВОД

Не так проста эта тема. Многое зависит от смысла, от структуры предложения и желания автора подчеркнуть нужное слово.
Эта те случаи, когда очень важен интонационный анализ.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Примеры:  Так вот и думай — хочешь как лучше, а выйдет как хуже.
Она всегда хочет сделать как лучше, а получается наоборот.
Я же для тебя хотел как лучше.
Справочник. Делай как знаешь
  КОНТАМИНАЦИЯ [лат. contaminatio - смешение] - 2) лингв. 
  возникновение нового слова или выражения в результате 
  смешения частей двух слов и выражений (напр., некорректное 
  «играть значение» как к. выражений «играть роль» и «иметь 
   значение»).  

